Open-source directory size comparison software
My TreeSize trial period has expired.
I tried both TreeSizeFree and Folder Size but they require a licence to open UNC dir paths.
Therefore I'm now looking for an opensource TreeSize equivalent to compare directory sizes.
Is there any?

Does JDiskReport work for you?

WinDirStat is a very commonly used open source Windows app for graphical directory size comparison.

Source code
